# Is it possible to generate a list of verbs that could be used in the same sentence as a given word in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is there a library (or combination of libraries) in Python that allows me to generate a list of verbs that can be used with a certain word?
For example when the given word is car: to drive, to crash...

I was thinking about possibly using NLTK but I couldn't find something that fits my needs.

Comment: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Would CMUs VerbKB help here at all? Out of curiosity, what verbs would be absolutely disqualified for the noun `car`?

Comment: @JonSG an example would be for example: "to eat"

Comment: I don't want to get pedantic but `"my car ate up the track!"` :-)

Comment: @JonSG yeaaaah "to eat" was a bad example :). I'll look into VerbKB thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this by downloading [Google Books Syntactic Ngrams](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/books/syntactic-ngrams/index.html) data. The VerbArgs dataset then might do the trick.
The datasets are huge so they will give you quite *complete* coverage of possible combinations; though there is also plenty of noise in there.